Intermittent file_get_contents errors on VMs connected via NAT
I run a number of Windows VM's (on a Windows host using Hyper-V), the VM's connect to the Internet via a NAT set up on the host (to avoid having public IP addresses on each VM) I've started to get frequent yet random errors displaying on all the VM's (they all run similar scripts and connect to the same server for requests) and I've started to get errors running PHP scripts that fail randomly and intermittently with an error A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond), yet the same script will run a few moments later. This has started occurring on all the VM's but different times.
I initially thought that it was the remote server the scripts were connecting to (as that's what the script error suggests) but that's not the case as I've run Wireshark on the host looking at the NAT network and the unsuccessful requests aren't even leaving the VM. I've also migrated one of the VM's to another host and it runs fine.
I've exhausted what I can think of to look at to try and resolve this other than rebooting the host, but I'd like to find the fault really. I have tried rebooting a couple of the VM's but this did not resolve the problem.
Any thoughts on what to check next would be appreciated.
Reading a few other posts related, I've already checked the MAC addresses and IP addresses of the VM's and none are duplicated.
Thanks in advance.

This turned out to be port exhaustion, I ran the following command
netsh int ipv4 set dynamicport tcp start=xxxxx num=xxxx

It was set to 16384 ports which was not enough, so I allowed a further 10000 ports and the errors started disappearing.
I'll need to look into the script/code/server settings to see why they're not being closed in a timely fashion, but it resolved the problem.
